# Bootstrap Modal-Manager disables overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Page overflow not working after I use
 `$('body').modalmanager('loading');` 
and
 `$('body').modalmanager('removeLoading');`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

To close the modalmanager loading window, try using `$('body').modalmanager('loading');` only instead of `'removeLoading'`. **'loading'** itself is used to **toggle** the loading state. (read documentation here - https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal)

Also ensure that you have included modalmanager js files after bootstrap js.

A similar issue is closed here (without any specific solution) - https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/issues/97

Comment: Is there anything that can help for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488322/bootstrap-modalmanager-window-hides-on-clicking-anywhere-else-in-backdrop?